# background-size: cover not working with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, image

Seeking some help with a responsive background image I have a border around.

I've been able to use `background-size: cover` in `<div>`s that have fixed dimensions.
I am trying to create an "inner border" that's transparent in [this demo](https://codepen.io/dickkirkland/pen/LYOJGbB).

In creating a border that is drawn from the inside, I'm using `box-sizing: border-box`.

Can someone help me understand why the background image isn't fully covering the div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `background-origin: border-box;`

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Works great. Is this because `box-sizing: border-box;` is being used? Does the usage have to match?

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with box-sizing

Comment: Ahh, I see where they are not related. I guess I'm just used to using images within <div>s https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin may help someone else. Thank you so much. Don't know why it's not showing mark as the answer, but I'll make sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

As temani-afif said use:
`background-origin: border-box;`

This solved my problem with the use box-sizing: border-box on a span with a background image that was resizine when a border was applied of a different size.